# How to store jars in github based maven repo

Tags: maven

Ive setup a github repo to store custom archetypes, and I can start a new project off these archetypes (on separate vm) using something like

```
 mvn archetype:generate -Dcatalog=https://raw.github.etc./archetype-catalog.xml
```

now i'm trying to store some 3rd party jars remotely in the same repo and reference them from a pom.xml as dependancies

First I installed the jar locally with

```
mvn install:install-file ..params..
```

the repo structure I have goes like:

**https://github.com/myappco/myrepo**

```
 |
 |___releases
 |           | 
              (group id)adobe.flex.messaging   (ie. adobe/flex/messaging)
                               common  
                                     1.0  
                                        (common-1.0.jar) 
                                        * trying to make this work
 |___snapshots
              |
               (group id)com.acme.archetypes   (ie. com/acme/archetypes)
                                my-archetype
                                           1.0-SNAPSHOT   
                                           * archetype resolved ok

 archetype-catalog.xml
```

The settings in my project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>adobe.flex.messaging</groupId>
  <artifactId>common</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>orb-snapshots</id>
       <url>https://github.com/myappco/myrepo/releases</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
```

I think I must be doing something dumb, because I can archetype:generate from the github repo archetype-catalog.xml. Can anyone see what I messed up?

Ta

Answer (score 0):

You need to `deploy` your artifacts in `github` using `mvn deploy`.  You would need to have set up `github` appropriately - perhaps similar to what is mentioned in [Hosting Maven Repos on Github](http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/).

Comment: Yea is the same link I used to setup, and works quite well - is there a difference between archetype storage and jar storage for maven dependancies? I used his method of -DaltDeploymentRepository, and it works fine for archetypes. I then push it to github. So far Maven error says: Could not find artifact flex.messaging:common:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in..{github repo url}

Comment: A follow up to the link that Raghuram posted is this solution, which automates the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14013645/82156